# Is arecord file type header streamed at the beginning?

Tags: linux, file, audio, header

I want to save a .wav file by taking the output of the following arecord command:

```
arecord -D plughw:1 -c1 -r 48000 -f S32_LE -t wav -V mono
```

It is set to one channel, sample rate of 48000, 32 bit depth. 
I don't want to use the option that automatically splits it in separate files, so I wrote a c program to take its output and stores it in a .wav file.
I am not able to understand if the header of the .wav file is streamed at the beginning of the arecord transmission, or if I should create and add that to the file from scratch.

Comment: Why not examine the first four bytes received?  If they are 0x52 0x49 0x46 0x46 ('R' 'I' 'F' 'F') then you have a header.